# .net winform application error on open

Tags: windows-xp, .net-framework

net 2.0 winform application that I am trying to run on a newly installed XP SP3 OS. The application works on other computers. Has anyone have any sugestions to what may be the problem

Comment: update:

error message for form applications "Application failed to initilize properly (0xc0000135)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [.NET Framework 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0856EACB-4362-4B0D-8EDD-AAB15C5E04F5&displaylang=en) and install it. .NET Applications compile to CIL then into bytecode, and must be run by the virtual machine.

Comment: it is already installed along with .net 3.5  but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: can you provide us with the error?

Comment: Okay I installed it and it works. I know the directory for .net 2 was there but maybe it was empty!. usually when you reinstall a framework it asks if you want to repair the prev version....it didn't in this case, which leads me to belive that it wasn't really there. Thanks John T.

Comment: You're most welcome!